# Ubuntu is outputting "Input/outout error." What does this mean?

Tags: live-usb

My OS isn't booting for some reason, and I'm going through the process of recovering it. However, I'll receive the message "Input/output error" on a file or folder, and when I restart, I'll be able to access that file or folder.

I am running an SSD, and I checked SMART, which told me I had 18 bad sectors, but that it was "above threshold."

What exactly is this error referring to? Could it be an issue with my USB drive that the LiveCD is on?

Comment: It sounds like your SDD is going bad, you can try downloading parted magic and preforming detailed tests.

Comment: At a similar question the problem turned out to be a bad image downloaded, you might want to burn Ubuntu again on the USB.
`http://askubuntu.com/questions/15168/input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-on-netbook?rq=1`